# How to convert binary to bytes in bash

Tags: arrays, bash, base64

How to convert the following go code to bash

```
    data, _ := base64.StdEncoding.DecodeString("nJpGBA==")
    fmt.Println(data)

    //Output
    [156 154 70 4]
```

I got up to here

```
    echo nJpGBA== |base64 -d
```

https://play.golang.org/p/OfyztKQINg9

Comment: What output do you expect? The same as in Go?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not a exact match, but:

```sh
echo nJpGBA== |base64 -d  | od -A n -t u1
```

Output: `156 154  70   4`

Note leading space and multiple spaces between.

Other solution. Assign it to an array:

```sh
val_array=( $(echo nJpGBA== |base64 -d  | od -A n -t u1) )
echo "${val_array[@]}"
```

Output: `156 154 70 4`

The command `od` dumps any binary files, by default in octal values. Here it reads from stdin, as no file is given.

- `-A n` suppresses the output of byte addresses
- `-t u1` prints one byte unsigned decimals

Comment: Very nice. Could you explain the `od` flags ? Will it work whatever the input is or will you need to adjust the flags ?